# Enroll visitor in Sitecore Engagement Plan using WFFM

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore-dms

I would like to Enroll a Sitecore visitor in a specific state of an engagement plan through WFFM. For this I took a Save Action Enroll in Engagement Plan and I have entered Parameters

```
<Host>smtp.gmail.com</Host><Port>587</Port><Login>mail@gmail.com</Login><Password>password</Password><IsBodyHtml>true</IsBodyHtml><enableSSL>true</enableSSL>
```

and I have also added State to that save action.

But when submitting the button following error is occured:
Enroll in Engagement Plan Error.

Please tell me what is the solution of this problem?

This error occurred in my LOG file:

> 2504 21:17:36 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\admin): Save item: master:/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions/Enroll in Engagement Plan, language: en, version: 1, id: {1B8ED61B-5B36-4C49-9736-2C4A87795D71}
>   10116 21:17:38 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\admin): Save item: master:/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions/Enroll in Engagement Plan, language: en, version: 1, id: {1B8ED61B-5B36-4C49-9736-2C4A87795D71}
>   2504 21:17:39 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\admin): Save item: master:/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions/Enroll in Engagement Plan, language: en, version: 1, id: {1B8ED61B-5B36-4C49-9736-2C4A87795D71}
>   2504 21:17:44 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
>   2504 21:17:58 WARN  no such user exists
>   Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
>   Message: no such user exists
>   Source: Sitecore.Forms.Custom
>      at Sitecore.Form.Submit.EnrollInEngagementPlan.Execute(ID formid, AdaptedResultList fields, Object[] data)
>      at Sitecore.Form.Core.Submit.SubmitActionManager.ExecuteSaving(ID formID, ControlResult[] list, ActionDefinition[] actions, Boolean simpleAdapt, ID sessionID)

Comment: Could you paste the exception you're getting?   There could be a large number of sources for this problem

Comment: Basically from what you have posted, you are trying to run a "Save Action" for your "Enroll in Engagement Plan" on/for "mail@gmail.com" that doesn't exists. Would agree with @MarkCassidy, on you posting more information regarding the exception.

Comment: I want to enroll a visitor in sitecore engagement plan using WFFM. For that I have created an Engagement Plan in Marketing Center. And on Home item's presentation I have set 'Get Our Newsletter' web form & on Submit button I chose 'Enroll in engagement plan' save action. Now on browser when I am entering my email id it is giving an error: Enroll in Engagement plan error.(the error that is for Enroll in engagement plan save action)

Answer (score 5):

The reason you get that error, is that Webforms are trying to enroll the associated ExternalUser in the engagement plan. Probably your visitor don't have an associated user and that is why you get the error.

Therefore you have two options:

1. First create a user based on the forms field and then associate that user with the visitor. This could be done in a separate action. After that you can apply your Enroll in Engagement plan action.
2. Write your own action that will enroll the current visitor in the engagement plan instead. But the entered data is not associated with the visitor in any way.

Comment: Hey Jens Thanx for reply but please explain a bit more because still I am not able to solve this!

Comment: Hi Gaurav. What do you need more explanation on?

Comment: how can I create user based on this engagement plan?

Comment: I am creating user manually with the same email id but how can I map this user to as a visitor to engagement plan. Please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: visitor.ExternalUser = user.Username;